# How to setup and use ThreeTenABP library

Tags: android, threetenbp, threetenabp

I can't get ThreeTenABP to work. Here's what I did:

1. import dependency in app build.gradle

   `implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'`
2. initialize the library in MyApplication.onCreate()

   `AndroidThreeTen.init(this)`
3. add MyApplication to Manifest

   `<application android:name=".MyApplication" ...>`
4. Use Instant to parse a String

   `Instant.parse(updatedOn)`

The only possible import for `Instant` is `java.time.Instant`. But this is not available until Android API 26, which is why I want to use ThreeTenABP in the first place.
I found some examples using an import `org.threeten.bp.Instant`, but this import/package cannot be found in my case.
I already did the infamous "Invalidate cache and restart", but to no avail. Is there anything else I am missing??

Comment: when you initialize Application, have you edit in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes, thx for the hint. I added this step to my question.

Comment: can't reproduce. I only did step 1 and I can see the class is present in `org.threeten.bp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay sorry guys for waisting your time. I was adding the dependency in the wrong app-module. Now everything is working.